# How to call delegates with returns sequentially?

Tags: c#, recursion, delegates, function-pointers

I'm looking to use Delegates to accomplish the damage reduction in a game in making. Specifically, the `ApplyDamage(damageAmount, damageType)` method of my character controller will call the `OnDamageBeforeResists(damageAmount, damageType)` delegate. This delegate returns a float, equal to the damage after mitigation by effects. So, anytime something adds an effect which reduces damage, this effect would add an anonymous function to this delegate, which is just a check for correct damageType, and a modifier then returning the modded number.

The issue is, I have numerous potential buffs or debuffs at any given time. Can I do something like

`damageAmount = OnDamageBeforeResist(damageAmount, damageType);`

And have it do them repeatedly, or will I have to use a collection of `Func<Float, Enum, Float>` and.iterate through them one at a time?

Also, if there already exists a cleaner solution, that i haven't considered I would welcome that.

Comment: What exactly bothers you with the solution of functions? It sounds pretty clean to me, and you can apply them with something like `funcs.Aggregate(0f, (a, b) => a + b(damageAmount, damageType))`.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis All delegates are multicast delegates, meaning every single delegate is already, inherently, a collection of methods to call, not just a single one.

Comment: It just didn't feel very clean to me, and if the delegates were an option, I would prefer to use them